# cmd.exe STDOUT is empty

Tags: c#, console

I starting cmd.exe process:

```cs
Process process = new();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.Start();

string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(input).Trim('\0');
process.StandardInput.WriteLine(data);
process.StandardInput.Flush();

Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

I need to get cmd.exe stdout, but stdout of process in empty. Result what i looking for:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.3086]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\dinikai>
```

I am tried to use `StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true`, but it didn't helped.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I am getting the x-y-Vibes.

Comment: "stdout of process in empty" I see no code that reads from `process.StandardOutput` so how do you know?

Comment: @Charlieface, i forgot to add it to question.

Comment: Has the application exited yet? It may not have flushed its stdout buffer yet. Having said that, it's a weird thing to do. Firstly why not just pass `/c yourCommand` to the `Arguments` property? And why not run whichever command it is you want directly, rather via `cmd.exe`? In fact, why not do it directly from C#? It certainly smells like an XY Problem.

Comment: I am doing an remote cmd shell. Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: Try to pass it a command like `/c echo hello`. Maybe the text above  (Windows version) is not going to the StandardOutput and is just printed internally.

Comment: I need one cmd, but /c is running one command and close a session

Comment: OK why do you need a remote shell?

Comment: You need to close _StandardInput_ before you can read _StandardOutput_.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid, It works, but how can i write to the `StandartInput` again?

Comment: If you have a new question, please create a new post.